# Instantiate a non static class to use across other classes without inheritance

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to improve my test framework and avoid too many co-dependencies across my many classes. This is for a test automation. I have a class called WebDriverSupport which contains mostly selenium webdriver methods like - Click(), entertext...

I have various page object classes that use these methods but I don't want to inherit the class. My current implementation is this -

```
public class WebDriverSupport{
public void ClickElement(IWebElement element){element.Click()}}
```

And then I have a page object class, let's say Homepage -

```
public class HomePage{
private WebDriverSupport Support{get;set;} = new WebDriverSupport();
public void ClickOnThatElement(){
Support.ClickElement(Element)}
```

My question is, is there a better way to implement my webdriversupport class without the homepage inheriting the class or me instantiating the class like above?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a dependency injection framework? Is that what you want? Why have private properties and not fields?

Comment: What's wrong with inheritance? or instantiating a class? Why do you think removing these is "better"?

Comment: @Icepickle I do use a dependency injection framework. That's what i'm trying to do so that i don't have too many coupled classes. How do you mean have fields instead of private properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `static` class using `Extensions`

```
public static class WebElementSupport 
{
    public static void ClickElement(this IWebElement element) 
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

and then use it by just `using` the class with extensions

```
using Namespace.With.Extension.WebElementSupport;

public class HomePage
{
    public void ClickOnThatElement()
    {
        Element.ClickElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm trying to avoid using static classes as well. I guess it's the most straight forward solution.

Comment: @MrB Can I ask why do you avoid static classes?

Comment: @MrB if you are trying to avoid it, then this shouldn't be the answer for your. Rafal, here you would loose the possibility to exchange the `WebDriverSupport` for a different implementation based on testing or production framework, I guess the OP prefers that (but then by using DI instead)